# Prevent rendering by Mathjax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mathjax

I am using vue-mathjax for compiling the math equations in my vue project. It is compiling the text between first bracket ().  I want to prevent compiling the string inside the bracket. In the documentation I found that, for $ sign, if we want to escape compiling, we need to use \$. So I tried this rule for the text inside ().

**My expected output:** (this is not math)

Here is what I tried: `\(this is not math \)`
The output: `\(this is not math \)`

It did not compiled the string as math equation, but is shows \ in the output.

If I try without , like `(this is not math)`
The output is `this is not math`
Mathjax compiles the string inside the bracket.

Can anyone help me with the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You have probably misconfigured MathJax's math delimiters to be `(` and `)` rather than `\(` and `\)`.  Try doubling the backslashes in your configuration and see if that helps.  If you have `inlineMath: [['\(', '\)'], ['$', '$]]` it should be `inlineMath: [['\\(', '\\)'], ['$', '$']]` (javascript strings use backslash as a special character, so you must use `\\` to get a literal `\`).  If you already have that, try `inlineMath: [['\\\\(', '\\\\)'], ['$', '$']]` (it may be that your content management system itself is using backslashes as special, so you need to double them a second time to get the javascript inserted into the page to have the needed double slashes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is with the configuration of **vue-mathjax**. I need to reconfigure the vue-mathjax, but I can not find a way to configure vue-mathjax. Can you help me with this? I was trying to configure the mathjax as the official documentation said. But I think the vue-mathjax is overriding the configuration.

Comment: For future generations, you'll find the delimiters talked about in `node-modules/vue-mathjax/src/components/vue-mathjax.vue` probably. Personally I had no use for multiple inline delimiters, so I just deleted `['(', ')']`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.  Including VueMathjax explicitly in my main.js file fixed it.  See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-mathjax

Before:
[image]

After:

```
main.js:

import VueMathjax from 'vue-mathjax'
Vue.use(VueMathjax)
```

[image]